# Wordpress select first post from the last added category(first)

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I select the last added post from the last added category and also display the post

Comment: I can't make an attemp since I don't even know, from where to start...I know how do display the posts from a certain category, but I don't know how to get the last id from the categories

Comment: Yeah solved using `query_posts('posts_per_page=1');`

Answer (score 1):

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
```

Comment: Use get_categories() to find the last category inserted. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories